# How can I reproject Shapefile in sinusoidal projection using ogr2ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, ogr

I have a shapefile in UTM WGS84 zone 32 and I would to reproject it in sinusoidal (MODIS like).

I would try using gdal ogr2ogr command, but I am not an expert and I got no results.

I tried with:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs EPSG:32632 -t_srs "+proj=sinu" \ input.shp output.shp
```

with the answer:

```
"ERROR I: Couldn't fetch request layer output.shp"
```

I have also tried to insert SR-ORG:6974 instead of +proj=sinu, but this was not recognized.

May you help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly GDAL/OGR's tools are a mess when it comes to the order of input and output parameters.

For ogr2ogr the first file name is the output, the last one is the input.

So try `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs EPSG:32632 -t_srs "+proj=sinu" output.shp input.shp`.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept this as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, your answer solved my problem. Thank you again!

Comment: Click the green check mark ✓ symbol ;)